# Incrementing GB of Ram for Docker Container in Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am following this tutorial https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#docker-settings-dialog to install docker in windows. I am stuck on the Settings section under Resources tab. My view of resources does not show how it is showing on that link. Is there a way to increase my Ram so I can have ELK to run. I installed the Docker Desktop application with the Hyper-V.

This is what I see in my settings.

[image]

What I should be seeing, but am not.

[image]

Comment: According to the page you linked, `The Advanced tab is only available in Hyper-V mode, because in WSL 2 mode and Windows container mode these resources are managed by Windows. In WSL 2 mode, you can configure limits on the memory, CPU, and swap size allocated to the WSL 2 utility VM.` Are you sure you aren't using the WSL2-backed version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you mention using Hyper-V, because of your screenshot (notably the WSL Integration tab), I suspect you may be running Docker Desktop in WSL2 mode, instead of HyperV mode. (WSL2 to my understanding is the newer, faster option in many cases).

With that assumption, to alter the RAM in your WSL 2 VM, you have to create a `C:\Users\username\.wslconfig` file with the VM settings. The details are described on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig) which is actually linked to by the page you mentioned.

This is an example of a `.wslconfig` file:

```
[wsl2]
memory=9GB # Limits VM memory
```

Note that this applies to *all* WSL2 VMs (I guess they are called distros?), which I'm not sure is exactly the right answer, since Docker seems to produce 2 distros by itself, plus whatever other distros you have (see `wsl --list`). Do you want to increase the RAM for *all* distros?

However, to quote [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions):

> WSL 2's memory usage grows and shrinks as you use it. When a process frees memory this is automatically returned to Windows.

This sounds to me like the `.wslconfig` memory setting is a max size, which is only allocated when needed, so I assume setting it for all WSL distros won't cause all of them to balloon up to 9GB immediately upon distro startup unless those distros try to use all that memory.

They go on to say:

> However, as of right now WSL 2 does not yet release cached pages in memory back to Windows until the WSL instance is shut down. If you have long running WSL sessions, or access a very large amount of files, this cache can take up memory on Windows. We are tracking the work to improve this experience on the [WSL Github repository issue 4166](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166)

I have experienced this ballooning memory issue on large ML jobs, so just something to be aware of.

So, the `.wslconfig` change has seemed to work for me. Another option that has helped me is increasing the `swap` size via `.wslconfig`, since my machine has limited memory.

Comment: And because despite how long I've been messing with this stuff, I *just* had an epiphany about it, I *think* `WSL Integration`  with a distro (in the Docker Desktop settings) refers to the availability to run Docker commands inside that distro (which is separate from the 2 Docker distros running all the Docker tools and containers). In other words, can I , from my default WSL Ubuntu distro, run Docker commands and access the same images and containers that are in Docker Desktop on the Windows host? That's turned on via the `WSL Integration` settings in Docker Desktop.</epiphany>